# Unable to invoke remote EJB on JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, ejb, remote-access, jboss-eap-6

**when I try to access an EJB running in JBoss EAP 6.2 from my remote client, I get the following exception:**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/xnio/OptionMap;)Lorg/jboss/remoting3/Endpoint;

    javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/xnio/OptionMap;)Lorg/jboss/remoting3/Endpoint;]
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:51)
```

**I am using these property for invoke remote ejb method.**

> endpoint.name=client-endpoint
>   remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
>   remote.connections=default   remote.connection.default.host=localhost
>   remote.connection.default.port = 8080
>   remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
>   remote.connection.default.username=admin
>   remote.connection.default.password=admin
>
> java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
>   java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:8080

**I have also used the below list of libraries**

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that list of libraries from? The versions seem a bit old for the platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty uncommon to use 8080 as the remoting port.. By default it's 4447 or an offset of that number.. Try using the following properties (taken from http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial)

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```